# How to achieve image changing on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

So I am trying to achieve the effect as such on this [website](http://www.theverge.com/2014/11/14/7216219/khyzyl-saleem-futuristic-car-art).

(*Near the bottom where you can hover over the image and it shows another as you move over it*)

Any ideas? I mean I know they are just overlaying the two images, but how they then display the far image using CSS/Javascript on hover? This is beyond me. I have tried reproducing it myself with no success.

Comment: never seen such feature.. looks interesting :)

Comment: See also: http://demosthenes.info/blog/819/A-Before-And-After-Image-Comparison-Slide-Control-in-HTML5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var main = document.querySelector('.main');
var one = document.querySelector('.one');
var two = document.querySelector('.two');

main.onmousemove = function (e) {
    var width = e.pageX - e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
    one.style.width = width + "px";
    two.style.left = width + "px";
}
```

```css
.main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.one {
    background-image: url('http://www.lorempixel.com/200/200');
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
.two {
    background-image: url('http://www.lorempixel.com/200/200/sports');
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-position: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a0y81qf3/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

So what's happening is, as the mouse hovers over the line, the width changes dynamically, if you inspect the element, you can see this as well.

Now, in the DOM structure, the brown car, the one being hidden is before the top image. So to achieve this, you can position the brown car absolutely, so it goes right behind the next image, and with javascript or jQuery add a listener for hover, on the image or that middle line that is used on the site, that will change the width of the top image (the silver one) in respect to the position of the mouse in the block of the image.

Essentially, the width of the background image should change by percentage to how far the mouse is from the left of the DIV, by percent i.e. if the mouse is at the middle, the width should be 50%.

Here is the js they use to do it, right from their site (I uncompressed it)

```
var ImageSlider = ImageSlider || {};
ImageSlider.Public = function(t) {
"use strict";
var e = t(".image-compare-tool"),
    i = t(".image-compare-images"),
    o = t(".image-compare-top img"),
    a = (t(".image-compare-bottom img"), function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var i, o = t(this).find(".image-compare-top"),
            a = t(this).find(".image-compare-bottom img")[0],
            n = a.getBoundingClientRect();
        i = "mousemove" == e.originalEvent.type ? (e.pageX - n.left) / a.offsetWidth * 100 : (e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX - n.left) / a.offsetWidth * 100, 100 >= i && o.css({
            width: i + "%"
        })
    }),
    n = function() {
        i.each(function() {
            t(this).on("mousemove", a), t(this).on("touchstart", a), t(this).on("touchmove", a)
        })
    },
    m = function() {
        o.each(function() {
            var e = t(this).attr("src"),
                i = t(this).parent();
            i.css("background-image", "url(" + e + ")")
        })
    },
    c = function() {
        n(), m()
    },
    r = function() {
        e.length > 0 && c()
    };
r()}(jQuery);
```

Comment: Good job! Only if it had human understandable function names it would be great!!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at html sources (Ctr + Shift + I in Chrome) you can see this element

```
<div class="image-compare-tool ICT-theverge">
  <div class="image-compare-images">
    <div class="image-compare-bottom"><img src="http://cdn2.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/2455624/khyzyl-saleem-plain-copylow.0.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image-compare-top" style="width: 6.158357771261%; background-image: url(http://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/2455620/khyzyl-saleem-plain-copylow1.0.jpeg);"><img src="http://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/2455620/khyzyl-saleem-plain-copylow1.0.jpeg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So here are images! So next you need to look at css.

```
.image-compare-tool
{
    max-width:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:999;
    margin:0 auto 1.5em 0;
}

.image-compare-images
{
    font-size:0;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    -ms-touch-action:none;
    -webkit-touch-callout:none;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
}

.image-compare-images:hover
{
    cursor:col-resize;
}

.image-compare-images img
{
    display:block;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
}

.image-compare-top,.image-compare-bottom
{
    z-index:0;
    height:100%;
}

.image-compare-top
{
    background-size:cover;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:50%;
}

.image-compare-top:after
{
    background-color:#fff;
    content:'';
    height:50px;
    left:calc(100%-5px);
    top:calc(50%-25px);
    position:absolute;
    width:10px;
}

.image-compare-top img
{
    display:none;
}

.ICT-SBNation .image-compare-top:after
{
    background-color:#c52126;
}

.ICT-SBNation .image-compare-top:before
{
    background-color:#c52126;
    content:'';
    height:100%;
    left:calc(100%-2.5px);
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:5px;
}

.ICT-TheVerge .image-compare-top:after
{
    background-color:#fa4b2a;
}

.ICT-TheVerge .image-compare-top:before
{
    background-color:#fa4b2a;
    content:'';
    height:100%;
    left:calc(100%-2.5px);
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:5px;
}

.ICT-Polygon .image-compare-top:after
{
    background-color:#ff0052;
}

.ICT-Polygon .image-compare-top:before
{
    background-color:#ff0052;
    content:'';
    height:100%;
    left:calc(100%-2.5px);
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:5px;
}

.image-compare-top:before,.ICT-Vox .image-compare-top:before
{
    background-color:#fff;
    content:'';
    height:100%;
    left:calc(100%-2.5px);
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:5px;
}
```

Here wea! You can implement same stuff by just including css and making same html structure and classes with just changing img paths...

And finally the js that i brazenly stole from the answer above:

```
var ImageSlider = ImageSlider || {};
ImageSlider.Public = function (t) {
    "use strict";
    var e = t(".image-compare-tool"),
        i = t(".image-compare-images"),
        o = t(".image-compare-top img"),
        a = (t(".image-compare-bottom img"), function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var i, o = t(this).find(".image-compare-top"),
                a = t(this).find(".image-compare-bottom img")[0],
                n = a.getBoundingClientRect();
            i = "mousemove" == e.originalEvent.type ? (e.pageX - n.left) / a.offsetWidth * 100 : (e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX - n.left) / a.offsetWidth * 100, 100 >= i && o.css({
                width: i + "%"
            })
        }),
        n = function () {
            i.each(function () {
                t(this).on("mousemove", a), t(this).on("touchstart", a), t(this).on("touchmove", a)
            })
        },
        m = function () {
            o.each(function () {
                var e = t(this).attr("src"),
                    i = t(this).parent();
                i.css("background-image", "url(" + e + ")")
            })
        },
        c = function () {
            n(), m()
        },
        r = function () {
            e.length > 0 && c()
        };
    r()
}(jQuery);
```

And the working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9gf59k00/
And my good luck...

Comment: This is not an answer... This is just copy and pasting code from that site into an answer....

Comment: What is answer then? Answer is theory? What theory you can suggest? Theory of the big bang? And i know im wrong cause i forgot js.

Comment: Anyone can copy and paste code, he wants it to be recreated.  So sure if he wants to use all their code he could have, but I'm sure he wants to understand what is going on rather than just copy and paste like a mindless zombie...

Comment: Lol... so hilariously. +1 just for fun

Comment: @SimplyCraig why he should reinvent the wheel? Only cause you want? If he wants to understand stuff - why he can't look at its source? Where is the license, that restricts him to look at their site's code?

Comment: @SimplyCraig It is an attempt to answer.

Comment: I am not sure why it would require so much of code? I did achieve same in few lines of javascript in below answer.  Is it because to support mobile devices too?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').on('mousemove', function(){
   var imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');
   if(imgsrc == 'img1.png'){
      $(this).attr('src','img2.png');
   }else{
      $(this).attr('src','img1.png');
   }
});
```

Comment: Pretty sure he is talking about the car image at the bottom that has a slider effect to show part of the img.  Not just straight replacing the image on hover.

Comment: @SimplyCraig - If you don't like the answer, you should downvote it, not flag it. Flags should be reserved for when the answer wasn't even an attempt at an answer (IE, if they left a comment, or a link, or another question, instead of an attempt at an answer, as an answer.)

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare I never flagged this post, so what are you talking about?

Comment: @SimplyCraig - Sorry, somebody recently flagged it anonymously, and since you had recently left a negative comment, I assumed it was you.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare oh ok, no wasn't me.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this without javascript, 
JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/k4915wwm/

Just…

```
div:hover {
   background:url("newImage.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully and do refer to the links provided in questions please!!

Comment: I guess the question should have been asked better.  I went to the link provided and it just had something where the image changed when you hovered over it.